# Leaving Macro Dialog Box In Place

Tags: excel, vba

If I want to run a set of macros from the worksheet, I touch <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and pick the first macro:

[image]

The macro runs, but the dialog box vanishes.

If I want to run several macros sequentially, I need to continue touching <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Is there any way I can configure the VBE to leave the Dialog Box open when a macro runs ??

Comment: Just curious why would you want to execute multiple macros via this method? Wouldn't it be easier if you create a dropdown of these macros to run or a menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a dirty solution just add `SendKeys "%{f8}"` at the end of your macros to call the macro window again ;)

**EDIT**:

got it now:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogRun).Show
```

**EDIT 2**

You also could create a userform with a list box which shows all important subs. This way you also could *exclude* subs you do not need or simply don't want to show up for whatever reason.
Also you could run subs this way which normally can't be run (missing dependency / parameter).

Comment: @Gary'sStudent got the not-dirty solution ;D

Comment: I like the first solution.  If I run a macro that contains only the `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogRun).Show`, the Dialog appears, I pick one, the Dialog vanishes, the macro I picked runs **twice** !! ..............very strange.......

Comment: oh wow... i will run some tests now... sounds very "funky" :D

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a macro to run the others in sequence?

```
Sub RunAll()

ColorMeYellow
FormatDownload
HyperKiller
NewCheck
ShapeKiller
SheetCounter

End Sub
```

---

or add flexibility with a ParamArray:

```
Sub RunAll(ParamArray runSequence() As Variant)

    For Each arg In runSequence
        Application.Run CStr(arg)
    Next

End Sub
```

Used like `RunAll "ColorMeYellow", "FormatDownload", "SheetCounter"`

Comment: A good suggestion, but then I am locked into a fixed sequence...........I want the flexibility of a menu without the extra overhead of bring  it up.